# What would a fusion reactor look like if it was on Earth?

Tags: science-based

Anyone that's seen a few episodes of '[The Simpsons](http://vignette2.wikia.nocookie.net/simpsons/images/9/90/Snpp-1-.gif/revision/latest?cb=20110502174607)' knows what a normal nuclear (fission) power plant looks like (cooling towers etc.), but I was wondering what a nuclear (fusion) power plant would look like. Would it also have cooling towers? Would it be much bigger/smaller than a nuclear (fission) power plant? Most nuclear (fission) power plants are made up of a few buildings and are usually near a water source, would the same be true for a nuclear (fusion) power plant?

Comment: This seems like a pure engineering question.

Comment: Meh, I don't think so.  I think Orlby is looking for some descriptions to think about doing story/worldbuilding.  You don't want to start with a completely backwards idea of what a good design would be.  And if you've not got any engineering/architecture background, how're you going to know?  You make spaceships with wings, because you know about aircraft... just like you can make a fusion reactor look like a fission reactor.  Right?  /snark  While I do think people should read some books, research and stuff, I don't think asking questions should be closed all the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now General Atomics is winding some magnets for the ITER plant to be completed in 2019, experiments in 2020, and full fusion in 2027.  I think they're planning on finishing the magnets in 2017 (6 +1 backup).  Each one can lift an aircraft carrier.

> The Central Solenoid is an essential system, a stack of six 120-ton magnets driving 15 million amperes of electrical current in ITER's fusion plasma to help stabilize it. Each coil will be 7 feet tall, 14 feet wide with 4 miles of superconducting cable...

From the site in question:

> The main feature of the 180-hectare ITER site in Saint Paul-lez-Durance, southern France, is a man-made level platform that was completed in 2009. This 42-hectare platform measures 1 kilometre long by 400 metres wide, and compares in size to 60 soccer fields. Building began in August 2010.
>
> The Tokamak Building will be slightly taller than the Arc de Triomphe in Paris. Measuring 73 metres (60 metres above ground and 13 metres below), it will be the tallest structure on the ITER site.

Comment: All this time and no pictures?  I would've said that [I can't decide without the pictures](http://www.drodd.com/simpsons-quotes/7-7.htm) — and yet, it was accepted, so what do I know?

Answer (score 1):

If the extrapolations made by the scientists currently working on fusion by tokamak are correct, it will be **huge**. You can get some idea from the scale of the ITER prototype, currently under construction. This won't be a power station. It will be a proof of concept, a check that scaling up works in favour of controlled nuclear fusion and doesn't introduce any new and unknown instabilities or other barriers to building a prototype fusion power plant.

Apart from the tokamak core, there's no reason to think that it'll generate electricity any differently to current power plants. Heat boils water, steam makes turbines go around, waste heat has to be dispersed via cooling towers. But whereas a large conventional or nuclear power station is a couple of gigawatts, the extrapolation suggests that a fusion power facility will have to be tens of gigawatts. So think of ten or twenty power stations all on the same site, all obtaining heat energy from the same fusion core.

The UK's total peak power generation capacity today is about 60GW. Having an entire country powered from one or two plants, or an entire continent from twenty or so, would bring its own challenges. Not least, extortion and terrorism.

Personally I prefer the other sort of fusion power. The sun is a fusion reactor. Carpet a small fraction of the Sahara desert with solar panels. This technology is proven, it's just politics and economics in the way.

Comment: Wouldn't the power lines from the Sahara to your country be just as much in danger as the fusion reactors (actually more since only part of it is in your own country, so you have to rely on other countries to not cut it)?

Comment: You'd be looking at a lot of redundant power lines, no single point of carastrophic failure. Also repairing a power line after sabotage could be done a lot more easily and faster than repairing a tokamak. So a lower risk level.  Oil and gas  pipelines are probably easier to sabotage and harder to fix than electricity transmission lines.